# TypeError when creating a new MatTable with Angular Material 2

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular2-directives, angular-material2

I'm creating a table using `mat-table` (from `MatTableModule`) but I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined
  at MatHeaderCell.CdkHeaderCell (table.es5.js:275)
  at new MatHeaderCell (table.es5.js:132)
  at createClass (core.js:12166)
  at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12011)
  at createViewNodes (core.js:13449)
  at createEmbeddedView (core.js:13327)
  at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14740)
  at Object.debugCreateEmbeddedView [as createEmbeddedView] (core.js:14070)
  at TemplateRef_.createEmbeddedView (core.js:11414)
  at ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (core.js:11130)
```

The error in the console appears related to the first occurrence of `<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>` tag.

---

I can't understand what is not working since the same code worked like a charm until yesterday evening.

The table in the component.html file

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" style="text-align:center">
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Creation date Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.created}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Device ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="deviceId">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Device ID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deviceId}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Failures Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="failures">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. Failures </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.failures}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

In my component TypeScript file I defined data as:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'created', 'deviceId', 'failures'];
  dataSource:MatTableDataSource<Element>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENTS);
  }
}

export interface Element {
  id: string;
  created: string;
  deviceId: string;
  failures: number;
}
const ELEMENTS: Element[] = [
  {id: 'Hydrogen', created: "123", deviceId: "ABC123", failures: 0},
  {id: 'Helium', created: "123", deviceId: "123ABC", failures: 3},
  {id: 'Lithium', created: "123", deviceId: "ABCEF5", failures: 0},
  {id: 'Beryllium', created: "123", deviceId: "ABC123", failures: 2},
  {id: 'Boron', created: "123", deviceId: "67ABC3", failures: 0},
];
```

So, apparently, data in TS and table cells in HTML are matched, what is causing this error to show up?

---

**Update**

Used library versions from `package.json`:

- `@angular/cdk`: `^5.0.0-rc.1`;
- `@angular/material`: `^5.0.0-rc.2`;

Comment: [**Works for me**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6to4n). I just noticed some mistakes in your interface: `deviceId` is missing and `lastUsage` is not being used and is mandatory (just remove it or put a `?` as I did in demo).

Comment: Thank you! Yeah the mismatch in interface and data was partially do to copy-pasting code. I've seen your demo and it seems clear but still it does not work in my project. I even copy-pasted the whole example component in my codebase and still getting the same error.

Comment: Note: I've fixed the lastUsage with deviceId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your package.json can you check the version of Angular material you have. 
What ever version you have, make sure your **@angular/cdk is the same version**.

That is likely you problem. I believe the problem is you may have higher version of angular material probably `"@angular/material": "5.0.0-rc.3"` and in that version the `renderer` parameter passed to `CdkHeaderCell` is not being passed any longer and for that reason you have to update     `"@angular/cdk": "5.0.0-rc.3"` as well

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've updated the question providing the versions for `cdk` and `material`, both are `5.0.0` but `material` is `rc.2` while `cdk` is `rc.1`.